# Ubuntu 18.04 without display manager

Tags: window-manager, display-manager

How to start Ubuntu 18.04 without a Display Manager?

What to put in `.xinitrc` to launch Ubuntu from TTY using `startx`?

**.xinitrc**

```sh
...
# What to exec here?
exec <ubuntu_session_thingy>
```

The closest I got to getting Ubuntu's Window Manager to start.

**.xinitrc**

```sh
...
# Looks like Ubuntu but not quite.
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
exec gnome-session --session=ubuntu
```